# XPATH for tr that has multiple text's in side it

Tags: xpath

I need XPATH for `<tr>` that contains text 'abc' in second `<td>` and text 'xyz' in third `<td>`

Tried but no luck.

Comment: _Tried but no luck._: not good enough. Show us what you tried so far. Also provide an example of the data you need to query and expected result of the query.

Comment: final String XPATH = "//tr[td[contains(.,'abc')] and td[contains(.,'xyz')]";

Answer (score 2):

```
final String XPATH = "//tr[td[contains(.,'abc')] and td[contains(.,'xyz')]";
```

Your expression actually almost selects what you want (once you fix the missing last `]`). You just need to specify positions of the `<td>` elements.

```xml
//tr[td[2][contains(.,'abc')] and td[3][contains(.,'xyz')]]
```

For the following XML document:

```xml
<document>
  <table>
    <tr>
       <td>foo</td>
       <td>abc</td>       
       <td>xyz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>foo</td>
       <td>bar</td>       
       <td>xyz</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</document>
```

this returns a node-set with the first `<tr>` element of the document in document order.